# Run into this error while using Pillow

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am using Pillow (4.3.0) to perform image quantization. When I run the image quantization function in PIL, I get this error saying **ValueError: dependency required by this method was not enabled at compile time**

Here is a MWE of my code

```
     from PIL import Image
     import numpy as np
     I = Image.open('test.jpeg')
     Q = Image.Image.quantize(I, colors = 64,method = 3, kmeans = 0, palette = None)
```

I is an RGB image (32x32x3). I am using Elementary OS. How do I sort this error out?

Comment: Maybe method=3 doesn't exist? It worked with method=2 and I couldn't find method=3 in the documentation:

`method – 0 = median cut 1 = maximum coverage 2 = fast octree`

Comment: It looks like your pillow was built without libimagequant support.

Comment: @klaus Documentation linked from the github page [does mention method 3](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.3.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.quantize).

Comment: @Goyo I was looking at an older version's documentation.

Comment: I found this in the README:
`Libimagequant is licensed GPLv3, which is more restrictive than the Pillow license, therefore we will not be distributing binaries with libimagequant support enabled.`

Comment: Please make your title more descriptive of the problem.